# There is no button in image (compositing). Button called mist

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, compositing-nodes

When I rendered animation (450 frames), I would like to composite it and add mist.

I closed Blender and than reopened it again. But when I go to the compositing and add image node with image in it, I didn't see mist button.

What can I do? I rendered animation for 4 days, so re-rendering isn't my option.

[image]

Comment: If you want to save channels, you have to use the .exr format, not png... I'm sorry but you have to re-render it if you want to have the mist pass. Although you can render only the mist pass to speed things up

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try some stuff.

Comment: Sorry. But how can I render mist pass.

Comment: From your image you don’t have Mist but you do have Depth. Assuming that is the actual depth from the render you can use the Depth in a similar way with a bit of Maths to convert into a suitable mix factor for your mist.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a tutorial for that?

Comment: This answer includes a method of using Depth as a mist pass : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/109192/29586

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: How did you render the images? did you save them as openEXR multilayer? If you didn't save the mist pass you will need to render again.

Comment: Thanks! I knew.

Comment: Hmmmm. Looks like despite the Image node having a Depth socket it seems that PNG files do not actually retain the depth (I'd assumed since it had the Depth it must have detected that the depth was also encoded in the image (which was something I was surprised that a rendered PNG contained!) - but after testing it seems it just returns 0 for the whole image). As @susu answered, your only option is to re-render.

Comment: @RichSedman PNG encode only RGB and unassociated alpha (if plugged in). No more. It is not a great format. OpenEXR was designed to hold linear data, so the depth pass can be stored unbound and linear. Why is there a socket for anything else is probably an error in the design of the image node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer. Re-rendering is your only option.

PNG will not save the mist pass, or any other passes. It will only save color and alpha by default.

If you need to save multiple layers use OpenEXR multilayer.

[image]

When you import the rendered image back it will have the corresponding sockets for the layers you saved.

[image]